# can i use some native Parquet file tools in Azure Logic App?

Tags: parquet, azure-logic-apps

Hi there I need to change format of parquet file to csv using only Logic app native tools. Is that even possible?

I did research of similar issues, I found how to use Azure Functions to change format, but it's not native Logic App tool.

Comment: Define "native".  Do you mean a **standard** connector in LogicApps that does it for you?

Answer (score 0):

There's a custom connector that will transform Parquet to Json for you.

It will also allow you to perform filter and sorting operations on the data prior to it being returned.

[image: Connector]

Documentation can be found here ... https://www.statesolutions.com.au/parquet-to-json/